# What did Hamechaber mean by "personal property" in Hilchot Tzedaka?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, shulchan-aruch

[SA Y"D 249](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.249.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he):

> כמה חייב ליתן [לצדקה] וכיצד יתננה:
>   שיעור נתינתה ... עד חומש נכסיו מצוה מן המובחר ואחד מעשרה מדה בינונית.
>   וחומש זה שאמרו שנה ראשונה מהקרן
>   מכאן ואילך חומש שהרויח בכל שנה:
>
> The amount of charity one should give is as follows: ... a fifth of one's property is most laudable. To give one-tenth is the average disposition. ... When they said a "fifth" they meant a fifth of the property the first year only and a fifth of the profits in succeeding years.

What did Hamechaber **originally mean by** "a fifth of the property the first year" -

- what's the 1/5 of which property?
- the first year of what?

Note: *I don't ask about the current Halachic trends.*